# IP Canonicalization, do I need to fix it?

Tags: domains, redirects, ip-address

I use ryte to analyze my webpage and it gives the following advice:

If the IP (173.###.###.###) of this domain gets called, it should redirect to the real homepage of this domain. Not redirecting requests on the IP can cause duplicate content issues.

Currently my server hosted multiple domains, but it has only one IP address. The main domain(most important domain) is www.example.com

So to improve SEO, should I let the access of the IP address, like below:

```
https://173.###.###.###
```

to be redirect to my main domain https://www.example.com?

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth would anyone attempt to go to `https://173.###.###.###?`

Comment: I'm guessing you have a dedicated IP address that isn't shared by other people?

Comment: IP addresses in https:// URLs are not a good idea. You can technically have certificates for IP addresses but this is rare and more complicated than for domains (until Let's Encrypt also start to provide those, as planned)